# apply_filters to content but ignore shortcodes

Tags: plugins, filters, shortcode, wp-editor

I want to prepare my content added via wp editor so it displays nicely, so I use `apply_filters` like so:

```
$ld = apply_filters('the_content', $ld);
```

That works fine for the page, but in the backend inside my wp editor I do not want to see the shortcode output, but the actual shortcode itself.

So now my shortcode `[sstest]` has a value of `eeeeee` and in the backend in the wp editor I see `eeeeee` instead of `[sstest]` .

How do I apply filters for the content but ignore shortcodes?

Comment: You want to render shortcodes in the backend editor?

Comment: Yes ( i think ). I want to show the actual shortcode, not execute its function.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Showing "the actual shortcode" is what happens by default. Are you applying the `the_content` filter to the editor content? I suspect that that is going to cause all kinds of bad.

Comment: Yes I am, so I can see it formatted. Am I supposed to use something else? I want to see this in backend: `[test]` and this on the page: `eeeeee` . Now, with the filters applied, i see `eeeeee` both on page (correct) and in the backend editor (incorrect)

Comment: How will you edit the shortcode if it is rendered in the editor?

Comment: Then I don't want it rendered. I want to be able to edit it. I want to see what I would see if I opened a post in the backend to edit.

Comment: You want to duplicate the backend editor somewhere else then? Sorry, this question is very unclear.